# UNIONed tables not counting all values

Tags: sql, oracle, count, union

Ok, so I'm not getting any legit errors or anything, but I'm trying to get it so that I can count the number of times a state is listed in two separate tables.  All of the states I want are showing up, but I know that there should be multiple values in some states, however each COUNT value is resulting in a value of 1.  Is this something I can fix?

```
SELECT shipping_address_state,
   COUNT(shipping_address_state) OVER (PARTITION BY shopper_account_id)
FROM orders 
WHERE shipping_address_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
UNION
SELECT vendor_state,
   COUNT(vendor_state) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_id)
FROM vendor
WHERE vendor_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
```

**EDIT**

So I took some advice, and I changed it to Union all.  I also added DISTINCT to the SELECT vendor_state and shipping_address_state parts.  It now got rid of all of the repeats in the state name column, but the counts are all still 1.  Without the DISTINCT keywords the repeated states show up, but as separate rows of data (like Pennsylvania will show up 3 times, but each has a count of 1). This is what it looks like now.  Anybody know why the COUNT is off?

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_state "State",
   COUNT(vendor_state) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_id) "Count"
FROM vendor
WHERE vendor_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT shipping_address_state "State",
   COUNT(shipping_address_state) OVER (PARTITION BY shopper_account_id) "Count"
FROM orders 
WHERE shipping_address_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
```

**EDIT**

Interestingly enough, I solved a big portion of the COUNT problem.  I just changed the PARTITION BY clauses so that it would PARTITION BY whatever I was trying to count.  Now they are being counted properly, but there are still recurring values in the State column due to them being in both tables.  Each of the columns just counts the number of times it shows up *in that table only*.  I tried changing it back to UNION instead of UNION ALL, but it didn't change anything.  Let's see if this can be done!

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor_state "State",
   COUNT(vendor_state) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_state) "Count"
FROM vendor
WHERE vendor_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT shipping_address_state "State",
   COUNT(shipping_address_state) OVER (PARTITION BY shipping_address_state) "Count"
FROM orders 
WHERE shipping_address_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
ORDER BY "State"
```

Comment: Some sample table data and expected output would be a great help

Comment: Rolled back your destruction. Do not vandalize your posts:(

Answer (score 1):

Change out the `UNION` for `UNION ALL`

`UNION` removes duplicate rows from the result set.
But `UNION ALL` shows the result set as it is.

So you can expect a better performance while using `UNION ALL` than `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

You should change UNION to UNION, also set a name for count columns like this:

```
SELECT shipping_address_state,
   COUNT(shipping_address_state) OVER (PARTITION BY shopper_account_id) cnt
FROM orders 
WHERE shipping_address_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
UNION ALL
SELECT vendor_state,
   COUNT(vendor_state) OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_id) cnt
FROM vendor
WHERE vendor_country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico')
```